# Can not initialize editor after update

Tags: java, aptana

After updating this morning when I open Aptana I recieve an error message that the editor can not be initialized, due to a java heap / out of memory error.  When this error occured I had 2.39GB of RAM free.  I ran the diagnostic test and this was the output:

```
Host OS: Mac OS X
OS Arch: x86
JRE Version: 1.6.0_33
JRE Vendor: Apple Inc.
JRE Home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Install Directory: file:/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/
Version: 3.2.2.201208201020
VM Arguments: -Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/aptana.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/AptanaStudio3.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

Workspace Directory: file:/Users/ddewbre/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/
Language: en_US
```

Comment: If it was working fine, and the update broke it, why not file a bug report?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
-Xmx512m
```

means the JVM won't allocate more than 512m to your Java objects *regardless of how much memory your machine has*. I suspect that you'll need to increase this to a suitable amount to avoid the above error.